# how to make the page loading bar loads when the ajax task begin?

Tags: html, ajax

how to make the page loading bar loads when the ajax task begin?
and how to make the `back` button review what was viewing before that `ajax` task

Comment: If you want great answers, you need to write great questions. Show us  _what you have tried_, or the community is very likely to close this.

Answer (score 0):

How to make the page loading bar loads when the ajax task begin?

- Just load the page with the bar enabled.  Then disable it when the page is finished loading.

How to make the back button review what was viewing before that ajax task?

- Assuming you are just dealing with ajax, you could post things with a hash tag and when you hit the back button it would revert the URL.

Comment: @Buffon provide some code that you have written so far with a more detailed question and I would be happy to look at it!